# Rocket not setting content-type text/html

Tags: rust, content-type

I am using the Rust Rocket framework for generating a simple webpage.

When go the the index page "/":

```
#[get("/")]
fn page_index() -> &'static str {
    r#"
        <title>GCD Calculator</title>
        <form action="/gcd" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="n" />
            <input type="text" name="n" />
            <button type="submit">Compute GCD</button>
        </form>
    "#
}
```

The server console tells me

```
GET / text/html:
=> Matched: GET /
=> Outcome: Success
=> Response succeeded.
```

But my browser tells me the Content-Type is **text/plain**.

How do I get Rocket to correctly respond with **text/html**. Am I doing anything wrong or does Rocket?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [guide about *responders*](https://rocket.rs/guide/responses/#wrapping) explains how to set the Content-Type of your response. In particular, you need [`rocket::response::content::Html`](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/response/content/struct.Html.html):

```
use rocket::response::content::Html;
#[get("/")]
fn page_index() -> Html<&'static str> {
    Html(r"<html>...</html>")
}
```

Note that you actually have to return an HTML document if you're going to set the Content-Type to "text/html". What you've posted in your example code is just a fragment of HTML. In practice, it's much easier to either put your HTML into a static `foo.html` file and use [`NamedFile`](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/response/struct.NamedFile.html) to serve it directly (which automatically sets the Content-Type), or [use templates](https://rocket.rs/guide/responses/#templates).

Comment: ```use rocket::response::content::Html;``` works great. I am still wondering why the Rocket console tells me ```"GET / text/html"``` but sends me ```"text/plain"```.

Comment: Oh, that "text/html" comes from the Accept header in the request, indicating what type the browser expects. It only affects what actually gets sent if you use [content negotiation](https://rocket.rs/guide/requests/#format).

Answer (score 5):

By default, Rocket will respond with text/plain so you have to override it using the content module it provides.

You can use the [Html](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/response/content/struct.Html.html) responder as such:

```
use rocket::response::content;

#[get("/")]
fn page_index() -> content::Html<&'static str> {
    content::Html(r#"
        <title>GCD Calculator</title>
        <form action="/gcd" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="n" />
            <input type="text" name="n" />
            <button type="submit">Compute GCD</button>
        </form>
    "#)
}
```